Django Migration file not being created despite showing its name and changes
It started seemingly out of nowhere, I'm unable to trace the origins of this issue but yesterday I made migrations just fine and I'm the only working on the project as of now, when I run python manage.py makemigrations it shows:
Migrations for 'app_name':
  app_name/migrations/0XXX_Do_stuff.py
    - Add field
    - Remove field
    - Alter field
    - Create model
    - Add field x to model`

When running migrations this shows up:
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: things, things
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'app_name', 'app_name_too' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

I can provide any code needed but I honestly don't even know where to start, Any help would be appreciated.
I use MySQL.

You mean migrate, can you share exactly what you ran? What if you remove the *.pyc and __pycache__ files.

@willeM_VanOnsem I just ran python manage.py makemigrations then python manage.py migrate
Tried deleting the pycache but I get the same result

@MazenMadouh: did you remove a migration file? (before makemigrations)?

@willeM_VanOnsem I think (not 100% sure as it has been a while) I did remove one before, but I made migrations and ran them after this and they worked fine.

the caveat is if you make a migration, migrate the database, and then remove the migration file and make migrations again, it will again make a file with 01234, so the database thinks it has already applied that one. That is why removing migrations after having applied them is a (very) bad idea.

@willeM_VanOnsem The latest migration number I have is 0145, in the message I get after python manage.py makemigrations the number of the migration file is 0146, which indicates correct order

@willeM_VanOnsem is there a way to fix this?
